# how to get the length of a property in vuejs

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

i have this json

```
{
   [{
    "status": "delivered"
  }, {

    "status": "delivered"
  }, {

    "status": "cancelled"
  }, {
    "status": "on Delivery"
  }]
}
```

i'm trying to get the total length of "status" :"delivered" in the json we have two "delivered" so how do i get the length of  "delivered" which is two and also how to i do for the rest status

this is my vue component

```
<script>
import axios from "axios";
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      orders: null,
    };
  },
  created() {
 axios.get("http://localhost:5000/api/orders").then((response) => {
      this.orders = response.data;
    });
  },

};
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can filter array and get length:

```js
const obj = { "orders": [{ "status": "delivered" }, { "status": "delivered" }, { "status": "cancelled" }, { "status": "on Delivery" }]}
const res = obj.orders.filter(o => o.status === 'delivered').length
console.log(res)
```

Answer (score 0):

At first, you provide an unformatted JSON.
I suppose you mean got handle this array:

```
const orderArray = [
      { "status": "delivered" }, 
      { "status": "delivered" }, 
      { "status": "cancelled" }, 
      { "status": "on Delivery" }
    ]

const lengthOfDelivered = 
orderArray.filter((order)=>order.status=='delivered').length
```

Furthermore, if you want to counting others status into a table:

```
let countTable = []
orderArray.forEach(order => {
    const idx = countTable.findIndex(item => item.status === order.status)
    if (idx !== -1) {
        countTable[idx]['count'] += 1
    } else {
        countTable.push({...order, count: 1})
    }
})
console.log(countTable);
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).